# how to create recycler view using card view with grid layout in android

Tags: android, xml

I want to create layout for my app. I already tried to create but I am not able to get the desired UI. Actually i am fresher in android development and I need help for improving my knowledge in android development. 
Please find attached snapshot below:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

i want to create this type of layout.
i already created like this here it is my code. raw_layout.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cvList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- Your content here -->


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ListImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="230dp"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/footerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/value_5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/value_15dp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/value_15dp">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/overflow"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ListTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="ListTitle"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/value_15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </ScrollView>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

my output is like that [my output][2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Check Below XML file for your Recycler View raw file

**raw_grid**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/cardView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/scale_10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/scale_5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/scale_5dp"
app:cardElevation="2dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/scale_150dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/dummy_1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/scale_10dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="HMS Scrap"
            android:textColor="@color/aluminum" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="(20)"
            android:textColor="@color/aluminum" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**activity_main**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/scale_10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class SubCategoryActivity extends AppCompactActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private GridLayoutManager layoutManager;
private LinearLayout llProgress, llError;
private AppCompatTextView tvEmpty;
private SubCategoryAdapter mAdapter;
private String title = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_business_info);

    init();
}

private void init() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    llProgress = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProgress);
    llError = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llErrorMessage);
    tvEmpty = (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEmpty);

    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    mAdapter = new SubCategoryAdapter(MainActivity.this, clickListener);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. :) @Akash